# Moving Multi image in swift (UIPanGestureRecognizer)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10.1

I am new to swift and xcode. using `xcode 10` and trying to make a buzzle like app where i need to move several images in the view. I found a lot about `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and `UITapGestureRecognizer` but all are working for the `UIImage` that has the last `addGestureRecognizer` only not for the rest.

Is there a way to detect which `UIImage` that i am touching to enable its movement?

Comment: please add your code you have tried

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: you can use paging in UIScrollView. Search 'how to create image viewer with UIScrollView in iOS' on google.e.g. https://www.codementor.io/taiwoadedotun/ios-swift-implementing-photos-app-image-scrolling-with-scroll-views-bkbcmrgz5

Comment: please see my answer below, It is working properly now.

Appreciate if you have enhancements to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution or actually what i was doing wrong:

You need to define a new variable of `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for each `UIImage` the variable is controlling one object at a time.

Thank you

This is what worked

```
@IBOutlet var imagesToMove: [UIImageView]!


let imagesNames = ["chk", "unchk"]

var gesturePanArray: [UIPanGestureRecognizer] = []
var gestureTapArray: [UITapGestureRecognizer] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var i = 0

    for imageItem in imagesToMove {
        imageItem.image = UIImage(named: imagesNames[0])

        imageItem.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.wasDragged(_:)))
        gesturePanArray.append(panGesture)
        imageItem.addGestureRecognizer(gesturePanArray[i])

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.wasTouched(_:)))

        gestureTapArray.append(tapGesture)
        imageItem.addGestureRecognizer(gestureTapArray[i])

        i = i + 1
    }

}

@objc func wasDragged(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
    let image = gesture.view

    view.bringSubviewToFront(image!)

    image!.center = CGPoint(x: (image?.center.x)! + translation.x, y: (image?.center.y)! + translation.y)
    gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

}

@objc func wasTouched (_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let imageTag = gesture.view?.tag
    if imagesToMove[imageTag! - 1].image == UIImage(named: imagesNames[0]) {
    imagesToMove[imageTag! - 1].image = UIImage(named: self.imagesNames[1])
    } else {
     imagesToMove[imageTag! - 1].image = UIImage(named: self.imagesNames[0])
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

1. For every image view, add a tag (if necessary maintain dictionary of tags and images)
2. In your gesture recogniser, get the image view on which user touches.
3. Get that view's tag to identify image view and identify the image accordingly.

Comment: Thanks I already manage to realize the issue which is about the same like yours .

Appreciate it.